# Can't Get Drupal Custom Drop Down Menu Position To Move With Screen

Tags: css, drupal-7

I am working with Drupal 7, and I made a custom drop down menu using css. Everything is displaying fine, but the drop down does not change position when the screen moves.

**Here are some screenshots:**

[image: Browser Smaller]

[image: Browser Expanded]

**Here is the css:**

```
**/*---------VISITORS SUBMENU---------*/
#block-menu-menu-visitors .content ul.menu{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 0 auto;
}**
#block-menu-menu-visitors .content ul.menu li{
 padding: 2px 15px 2px 15px;
 list-style-type: none;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #ffff90;
}

#block-menu-menu-visitors .content ul.menu li:hover{
 padding: 2px 15px 2px 15px;
 display: inline-block;
 background-color: #ffffaa;
}
```

Any ideas on how to get the position to be the same relative to the screen size?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing your HTML. But here's a guess: put it inside your main container, and offset it to the desired position with a negative `left` value. `position:absolute` may be necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out the problem. In my php, the div that I had placed my submenu in was floating by itself. My solution was to wrap it in the same div that the main menu was, and it worked out perfectly. There was never a problem with writing of the css or html, just a location issue. Consider this issue solved.